# Livewire 3 Model Binding

Tags: laravel-livewire

### *Estoy tratando de crear un registro de usuarios con Livewire 3 usando model binding*

### *este es mi componente Register*

### *le hice un dd y si me agarra el campo contraseña pero a la hora de crear el registro salta el error*

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class Register extends Component
{
    public User $user;

    protected function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'user.name' => 'required|min:3',
            'user.email' => [
                'required',
                Rule::unique('users', 'email')->ignore($this->user),
            ],
            'user.image' => 'nullable|url:http,https',
            'user.password' => 'required|min:3',
        ];
    }

    public function mount(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function save()
    {
        // dd($this->user);
        
        $this->validate();
        $this->user->password = bcrypt($this->user->password);
        $this->user->save();

        return to_route('registro')->with('msg', __('User saved'));
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.register');
    }
}
```

---

### *y esto es mi vista.. no me agarra el campo contraseña,me da el error de validación The password field is required*.no encuentro como arreglarlo. Ayuda por favor

### no encuentro el error, en pocas palabras me quede atascado

```
<div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-2 mx-auto mt-3 w-52">
    @if (session('msg'))
        <span class="w-full p-1 mt-2 mb-2 text-center bg-slate-600">{{ session('msg') }}</span>
    @endif
    <form wire:submit="save" class="p-3 m-2 space-y-2">
        <input type="text"wire:model="user.name"/>
        @error('user.name')<span class="">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
        <input type="email" wire:model="user.email"/>
        @error('user.email')<span class="">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
        <input type="url" wire:model="user.image"/>
        @error('user.image')<span class="">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
        <input type="password" wire:model="user.password"/>
        @error('user.password')<span class="">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
        <button class="w-full p-3 border border-red-600" type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

(I do not speak any Spanish so used a translate function here :))

Creo que esto se debe a que $password es una propiedad oculta en el objeto de usuario. Echa un vistazo al modelo de usuario y verás que está configurado en la matriz $hidden. No lo retires de allí, ya que debería estar oculto. Intenta crear otra propiedad en el objeto Livewire llamada public $password.

```php
public $password;

protected function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'user.name' => 'required|min:3',
        'user.email' => [
            'required',
            Rule::unique('users', 'email')->ignore($this->user),
        ],
        'user.image' => 'nullable|url:http,https',
        'password' => 'required|min:3',
    ];
 }

public function save()
{
    $this->validate();
    
    $this->user->password = bcrypt($this->password);
    $this->user->save();
}
```

Asegúrate de cambiar la vista aswel.

```
<input type="password" wire:model="password"/>
@error('password')<span class="">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
```

Comment: Thanks brother if it worked for me